# using fstream object created as class member

Tags: c++, file, class, copy, fstream

I have an fstream object declared in my class like this (just an example):

```
class Asd {

  public:
  Asd();

  private:
  std::fstream stream;

};
```

Now when the constructor is called I want to specify the fstream parameters like this

```
Asd::Asd() {

  this->stream = std::fstream(file, std::fstream::in);

}
```

and then use that stream in all class functions that I have, but it doesn't work. One error VS is giving me is:

```
no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

So I read up on that and all I could find is that I can't (or rather: shouldn't) copy a stream and indeed I don't even want to do that. Someone said one could add this to the constructor:

```
Asd::Asd() : stream(file, std::fstream::in) {

  ...

}
```

but it prints the same error and I don't know what to do... Also someone else said I have to reference the object but I don't know how?? I just want this to work but I can't figure it out :(

Edit: this is the full error message

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(860): error C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(177) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =(const std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(604): error C2249: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ios(177) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
```

Comment: file is an std::string but even when I put a char const* in it the initialiser prints the same error. And @Manu343726 should I always prefer to construct outside the constructor body or only in this case? I find it a little awkward and am used to putting all the assignments inside the constructor ^^ But that doesn't say much because I'm a beginner

Comment: I think you should prefer the initializer list in all cases. I certainly do and most of my constructors end up with an empty body.

Comment: I think the error message has nothing to do with the code in the question, other than the fact you have a class with an `fstream` member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what you write, it seems you still have an assignment in your constructor. Try if this works:

```
class Asd {
public:
    Asd(char const* file);

private:
    Asd(Asd&);
    void operator= (Asd&);

    std::ifstream stream;
};

Asd::Asd(char const* file): stream(file) {}
```

Using the member initializer list to construct the object avoids default constructing it and then having to set it up later. If you really want to first construct the stream and set it up later, you can't use assignment because streams are neither copy constructible nor copy assignable. However, you could just open it, e.g.:

```
Asd::Asd(char const* file) { stream.open(file); }
```

By using `std::ifstream` it isn't needed to pass `std::ios_base::in` (or any other variation at getting a this value through classes indirectly derived from `std::ios_base` like `std::fstream`) to the constructor or to `open()`: `std::ios_base::in` is automatically added to whatever are passed to `std::ifstream`'s constructor or to `std::ifstream::open()`. Also, `std::ifstream` is a somewhat simpler class than `std::fstream`. It should be smaller and is probably faster to construct.

Based on Mooing Duck's comment I have added a private copy construct and a private assignment operator, in the hope that the compiler will point you at one of these in case you try to copy construct or copy assign an `Asd` object. Note that an attempt is made copy object when passing the to a function taking the argument by value or when returning an `Asd` object. It is quite possible that the assignment in your constructor was one place where the compiler complained about not being able to copy a stream but there may be other places where a copy attempt is made.

Comment: Actually, the error looks to me like the one MSVC9 gave when you try to copy an object that has a member who's copy constructor is private and undefined.  MSVC9 won't tell you where the copy was made though.

Comment: OP's error messages differ from those here: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/Kd1F but apperently this version also doesn't tell you where the copy is. (See that `main` is not in the output at all)

Comment: Thanks for this... unfortunately I did exactly what you have written but the errors persist. I will have to look into this some more but sadly I have to do that tomorrow as I have no time now... I will reply back in this thread with hopefully good news :( EDIT: oh and I put the full error message in my original post

Comment: @AurelleDenby: Try adding a private copy constructor and copy assignment: you are probably trying to copy an `Asd` object which wouldn't work because the stream inside can't be copied.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks I will look into this tomorrow and I hope to solve it with your help.. I will reply here then ^^