# C++ homework. Arrange names in payroll in order. Using arrays

Tags: c++, function, fstream

Please assume headers are already in place for my code example.

I can't seem to get this working.

The error says:

> `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\fstream(890): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'`

Here is my homework question:

> **Question: Sorting Employees by a key value.**
>
> For this assignment you are to extend the Employee Payroll Report program you wrote previously. Your program should be modified to allow data for up to 15 employees to be entered. Regardless of which order the employee data is entered, the detail lines of the report should be printed in ascending employee name order. In other words, you should first sort the employee data before generating report. Your program should include the Employee and Payroll Report classes that were described for the previous assignment.

### Here is my code...

#### Employee class:

```
    class Employee 
    {
    public:
        Employee();
        int input();
        void calculate();
        void display();
        void input_storage(Employee []);
        void sort(Employee[], int);
        void swap(Employee &, Employee &);
        void set_name(string);
        string get_name();
        void set_hours(double);
        double get_hours();
        void set_rate(double);
        double get_rate();
        void set_ovrhours(double);
        double get_ovrhours();
        void set_sal(double);
        double get_sal();
        void set_ovrsal(double);
        double get_ovrsal();
        void set_count(int);
        int get_count();

    private:
        string name;
        int count;
        double hours, rate, ovrhours, sal, ovrsal;
        ifstream infile;

    };

    Employee::Employee()
    {
        count=0;
        infile.open("payroll.txt", ios::in);
        if (!infile)
            cout << " Error: Could not open input file. \n";
    }

    void Employee::set_name(string new_name)
    {
        name=new_name;
    }

    void Employee::set_hours(double new_hours)
    {
        hours=new_hours;
    }

    void Employee::set_rate(double new_rate)
    {
        rate=new_rate;
    }

    void Employee::set_sal(double new_sal)
    {
        sal=new_sal;
    }

    void Employee::set_ovrsal(double new_ovrsal)
    {
        ovrsal=new_ovrsal;
    }

    void Employee::set_ovrhours(double new_ovrhours)
    {
        ovrhours=new_ovrhours;
    }


    int Employee::input()  
        {           
            if (infile >> name >> hours >> rate)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

    void Employee::calculate()  
        {
            ovrhours=hours-40;

            if (ovrhours>=10)
                {
                    ovrsal=(10*(1.5*rate))+((hours-50)*(2*rate));
                    sal=(40*rate)+ovrsal;
                }

                else if (ovrhours>0 && ovrhours<10)
                {
                    ovrsal=ovrhours*(rate*1.5);
                    sal=(40*rate)+ovrsal;
                }

                else
                {
                    ovrhours=0.0;
                    ovrsal=0.0;
                    sal=hours*rate;
                }
        }

    void Employee::input_storage(Employee storage[])
    {
        storage[count].name=name;
        storage[count].rate=rate;
        storage[count].hours=hours;
        storage[count].ovrhours=ovrhours;
        storage[count].ovrsal=ovrsal;
        storage[count].sal=sal;
        count++;
    }

    void Employee::sort(Employee storage[], int n) 
        {
            n=count;
            for (int i=n-1; i>0; i--)
                for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                    if (storage[j].name > storage[j+1].name) swap(storage[j],storage[j+1]);
        }

    void Employee::swap(Employee &a, Employee &b)
    {
        Employee temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }



    void Employee::display() 
        {   
            cout << "Report is created in your respective workspace." << endl;

        }

    string Employee::get_name()
     {
         return name;
     }

    double Employee::get_rate()
     {
         return rate;
     }

     double Employee::get_ovrhours()
     {
         return ovrhours;
     }

      double Employee::get_hours()
     {
         return hours;
     }
        double Employee::get_sal()
     {
         return sal;
     }
        double Employee::get_ovrsal()
     {
         return ovrsal;
     }
```

#### Payroll Report class:

```
    class PayrollReport
    {
    public:
        PayrollReport();
        void insertDetail(Employee [], int);
        void border(int);
        void display_total(Employee[]);
        void columnheadings();
        void indent(int);
        void reportheader();
        void skiplines(int);

    private:
        double tot_hours, tot_ovrhours, tot_ovrsal, tot_sal;
        ofstream outreport;
    };


    PayrollReport::PayrollReport()
    {
        outreport.open("report.txt", ios::out);
        tot_hours=0.0;
        tot_ovrhours=0.0;
        tot_ovrsal=0.0;
        tot_sal=0.0;

    }   

    void PayrollReport::indent(int n)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            outreport << " ";
    }
    void PayrollReport::skiplines (int n)
    {
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    outreport << endl;
    }

    void PayrollReport::reportheader()
    {
        border(100);
        skiplines(1);
        indent(37);
        outreport << "EMPLOYEE PAYROLL REPORT"<<endl;
        border(100);
    }


    void PayrollReport::columnheadings()
    {
    outreport << endl<<setiosflags(ios::right)
    << setw (15) << ' ' << setw (10) << "Hourly"
    << setw(10) <<" " << setw(10) << "Overtime"
    << setw(10) << "Overtime" << setw(10) <<"Total" << endl
    << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw (15) << "Name"
    << setiosflags(ios::right)
    << setw (10) << "Rate" << setw(10) << "Hours" << setw(10) << "Hours"
    << setw(10) << "Salary" << setw(10) <<"Salary" << endl;
    border(100);
    skiplines(1);
    }


    void PayrollReport::insertDetail(Employee storage[], int n)
    {
        outreport << setiosflags(ios::right)<<setprecision(2) << std::fixed <<setw(15)<< storage[n].get_name() << ' ' << 
                    setw(10)<<storage[n].get_hours()<< setw(10) << storage[n].get_rate() << setw(10)<< storage[n].get_ovrhours() << setw(10)
                    << storage[n].get_ovrsal() << setw(10) << storage[n].get_sal() << endl;


        tot_hours+=storage[n].get_hours();
        tot_sal+=storage[n].get_sal();
        tot_ovrhours+=storage[n].get_ovrhours();
        tot_ovrsal+=storage[n].get_ovrsal();

    }

    void PayrollReport::display_total(Employee[])
    {
        border(100);
        skiplines(1);
        outreport << setiosflags(ios::showpoint | ios::fixed | ios::right)
        << setw(15)<<"Totals"<<setw(22) << tot_hours
        << setw(10) << tot_ovrhours
        << setw(10) << tot_ovrsal
        << setw(10) << tot_sal << endl;

        skiplines(4);
        border(100);
        skiplines(1);
        border(100);

    }

    void PayrollReport::border(int n)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            outreport << "-";
    }
```

#### Main function:

```
    int main()
    {

        int loopcount;
        Employee x;
        Employee storage[15];
        PayrollReport p;

        p.reportheader();
        p.columnheadings();


        while (x.input()==1)
        {       
            x.calculate();
            x.input_storage(storage);

            loopcount++;
        }

        x.sort(storage, loopcount);

        for (int i=0; i<loopcount; i++)
        p.insertDetail(storage, loopcount);


        p.display_total(storage);
        x.display();

        cin.ignore();
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole lot of code there unrelated to the actual problem!

Here is how you can reduce it to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to make it easier for us to help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee();
    void swap(Employee &, Employee &);
private:
    int count;
    ifstream infile;
};

Employee::Employee()
{
    count=0;
    infile.open("payroll.txt", ios::in);
    if (!infile)
        cout << " Error: Could not open input file. \n";
}

void Employee::swap(Employee &a, Employee &b)
{
    Employee temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

This makes it clearer that the issue is that the *copy constructor* of `Employee` is implicitly deleted because `infile` has a deleted copy constructor. This copy is called in `Employee::swap()`.

See [using fstream object created as class member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18522108/78845) for an explanation.

It seems that the best way to solve this is by removing all knowledge of `infile` from `Employee` (should file-handling be the responsibility of an `Employee` class?).

I would do this by removing `int Employee::input()` and replacing it with an `operator >>` overload for `Employee`, something like:

```
std::ifstream& operator >>(std::ifstream& is, Employee& employee)
{
    std::string name;
    double hours, rate;
    if (is >> name >> hours >> rate)
    {
        employee.set_name(name);
        employee.set_hours(hours);
        employee.set_rate(rate);
    }
    return is;
}
```

You'd then need to change the way the file is opened and read in your `main()` function:

```
// [...]
    p.columnheadings();

    std::ifstream infile("payroll.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        // N.B: Report errors on stderr!
        std::cerr << " Error: Could not open input file. \n";
    }

    while (infile >> x)
    {
        x.calculate();
        x.input_storage(storage);

        loopcount++;
    }

    x.sort(storage, loopcount);
// [...]
```